# Linux Ext4 Filesystem Explanation Needed, 19 million One byte files equals 80+GB?

Tags: linux, ssd, filesystems, ext4

Here's the deal, I am dupe checking domains for my crawler, I have 145 million domains to dupe check on the fly.

Storage Consumed:

```
80GB for 19 million files
```

To do so, I am creating a directory structure off of the first four letters of the domain, then creating a one byte file signifying I have seen this domain before.

```
s/u/p/e/superuser.com
```

I create the directory structure like above to keep anyone directory from having an unreasonable amount of files in it...

Domain/File Location Details:

```
Domain: superuser.com
Root Directory: /home/tmc/tech/Data/Dupes/Domains/
Directory: s/u/p/e/
File Path: s/u/p/e/superuser.com
File Contents: .
```

Now, I suspect strongly that the storage usage somehow has something to do with the amount of directories and files being created, however, creating just the directories does not result in extreme storage usage, so it has something to do with having those directories populated, again, I am trying to figure this out, this is what I suspect at this time.

Can someone please explain to me how the linux ext4 file system works in terms of storage consumption in relation to directories, files, and populated directories with files?

Comment: I have been banging my head against the desk for 2 days now, any ideas at all are greatly appreciated...

Comment: What is the average size of the files stored?

Comment: They are all 1byte

Comment: This may be a really stupid question - why not use a database or something built for this type of data tracking instead of doing it through the file system?  I would think it would be a lot faster then having to traverse up and down through 4/5 levels of directories.

Comment: This may be a really stupid question 2- How do you store anything meaningful in a 1 byte file?

Comment: The file itself is the data, so like, if I come across a domain with my crawler, my code says, if(file_exists(<path_to_domain>) == false) then I know that I have not crawled that domain yet... And when I start to crawl that domain, before I was putting a period inside the file, now I am just touching it, hopefully just touching the file will work out =]

Comment: @kazoni I actually found previously, its exponentially faster to do a file_exists, than to traverse an index of 145 million rows..., now if I have to do a listing of the directories, or something like that, then yes you are correct

Comment: Then you did your database wrong.

Comment: @Cylindric, quite possibly =]

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I've made this sort of crawler before, and there is no easy "I win" solution. Keep at it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert on ext4 but like most file systems it allocates space for files in blocks. The default block size for ext4 is 4096 bytes, so each of your one byte files actually uses 4096 bytes on disk. 19 million times 4096 gives you about your 80GB.

If you are just using the files as markers you may be able to use files which are 0 bytes long, in that case the system won't allocate a block for the file.

Comment: Hrmm, that math makes a lot of sense, Let me see what happens when I try just touching the files